# MouseOver item combobox extjs 4

Tags: forms, extjs, autocomplete, combobox

I'm trying to do a sort of temporary form autocomplete on mouse over of a combobox item. My combobox has a remote store and I would that on item hover the other fields of the form are compiled with the other information from combo store while the mouse is on an item. There isn't a mouseover event for comboboxes items so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a mouseover listener to the div element that is wrapping the combobox like so:

```
myCombo.bodyEl.on('mouseover', function(e, t, eOpts) {
    //Do something
});
```